# How to Design a Android Overlay Layout

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a alert dialog which will show like the picture.
Im trying to use frame layout but can't make the it right like the picture. In my current layout I used an imageView and textview.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src=""/>
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@strings/text"
/>
</FrameLayout>
<!---<other layouts--->

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, you can use an Activity with transparence

Comment: @wyoskibum added my code .. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

A FrameLayout will stack the Views, causing them to overlap each other.  If you want one directly above the other, consider using a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with the orientation set to vertical.

Update:  Try this, replacing your FrameLayout with a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@strings/text"
    />

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously fill in the `src` parameter for the ImageView with your image.

Comment: im actually trying to make it like the image that i have attached. but i couldn't figure out how to do this using the framelayout.

Comment: @jquery404 do you mean you want the layout like the image, or do you mean that you just want it to look like a dialog with the modal background?  In any case, try my above layout code.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Activity it represents your overlay.

Put this in your onCreate

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //importan no title show
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.overlay);

 }
```

put this in styles.xml

```
  <style name="FloatingPopup" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In your manifiest  declare the activity thath looks like a overlay and add the theme

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourOverlayActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FloatingPopup" >
    </activity>
```

It looks like a semitransparent activity and now you can custom with xml layout editor.